# I want to upload a file to uploads folder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I tried But i cant get it fixed
This is my code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="patientEnquiry" method="post" class="form" action="" > 

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"  required="required" maxlength="100" class="form- 
 control">
 </div>   
 <input type="file" id="passport" name="passport" class="required">
 </form>
 <button class="request"  id="patientsub" >submit</button>
```

and This is what i placed in functions.php

```
$target_dir = get_home_path().'wp-content/uploads/';

$file = $_FILES['passport']['name'];
$path = pathinfo($file);
$filename = $path['filename'];
$ext = $path['extension'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['passport']['tmp_name'];
$path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
}else{
move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
}
```

when i try to echo $file; i'm not getting anything please help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is getting path you need to use ABSOLUTE path.

```
$target_dir = str_replace('\\', '/', ABSPATH)."wp-content/uploads/";
```